# How to remove the WixToolset program name from the .msi file details?

Tags: wix

I'm building a .msi Windows Installer file with the WixToolset 4.0.3. After building it, it shows a note inside the file details:

[image]

Is there a chance to remove this note while building the .msi file? Inside the Windows Explorer, I can remove it manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Installer specification says that the tool that created the MSI package is supposed to be placed in that field. You could write another tool to modify the summary information stream directly but that would not be to Windows Installer spec.